# Question about the NSArray

Tags: iphone

```
groupContentList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [Product productWithType:@"Device" name:@"iPhone"],
                    [Product productWithType:@"Device" name:@"iPod"],
                    [Product productWithType:@"Device" name:@"iPod touch"],
                    [Product productWithType:@"Desktop" name:@"iMac"],
                    [Product productWithType:@"Desktop" name:@"Mac Pro"],
                    [Product productWithType:@"Portable" name:@"iBook"],
                    [Product productWithType:@"Portable" name:@"MacBook"],
                    [Product productWithType:@"Portable" name:@"MacBook Pro"],
                    [Product productWithType:@"Portable" name:@"PowerBook"], nil];
```

How to print  the value  of  groupcontestList

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve a string representing `NSArray` contents with `-description` method. This is implicitely used with:

```
NSLog(@"%@", groupContentList);
```

It will in turn invoque `-description` method on each of its elements (which defaults to printing address of object as defined in `NSObject`).

So if you want it to be usable, you have to define a `-description` method for your `Product` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
For(Product* prod in groupContent){
    NSLog(@"type=%@ name=%@", prod.type, prod.name);
}
```